# IBM Worklight Android 4.4 issue, JSON Store stopped working

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have just upgraded my N4 to Kitkat and tested some of old apps being developed using IBM Worklight. It was shocking for me that **JSON Store** stopped working, I am submitting below log please check. Does anyone else face the same issue ?

> 11-27 11:48:03.078: I/jsonstore-core(23424): Performing migration to
>   JSONStore 2.0 11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424): Unable to
>   create jsonstore directory 11-27 11:48:03.078:
>   E/jsonstore-core(23424): java.lang.Exception: Unable to create
>   jsonstore directory 11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.checkVersionMigration(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:72)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.dispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:220)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:87)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:113)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$SerialExecutor$1.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:147)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 11-27 11:48:03.078:
>   E/jsonstore-core(23424): Error during provision 11-27 11:48:03.078:
>   E/jsonstore-core(23424): java.lang.Exception: Unable to create
>   jsonstore directory 11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.checkVersionMigration(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:72)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.dispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:220)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:87)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:113)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$SerialExecutor$1.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:147)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   11-27 11:48:03.078: E/jsonstore-core(23424):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>
> init notification error:----->{ "src": "initCollection", "err": -1,
>   "msg": "PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE", "col": "Notification", "usr":
>   "test", "doc": {}, "res": {} }  [wl.jsonstore]
>   {"src":"initCollection","err":-1,"msg":"PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE","col":"Notification","usr":"test","doc":{},"res":{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONStore, a Worklight feature that enables persistent storage of JSON documents, is not working as one of the third-party libraries supporting this feature is using an API that is no longer available.

Here is [LINK](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/android_4_4_kitkat_support_is_here?lang=en) to read more.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Amit Kumar's answer, it should be noted that a fix will be released in the near future for Worklight 5.0.6.x and 6.0.0.x as well as the upcoming 6.1.0, where the feature compatibility is restored.