# How to open the FIPS enabled json data's in worklight App

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have downloaded the sample app for Encrypting JSON store using FIPS from IBM Worklight 6.0 Getting started modules. 
Using the available PDF, I added all the necessary files in the Android project and I modified the src java file as per the instruction provided by the PDF.

When checking my application in Emulator, I am unable to initialize my JSON Store, and the error showing in Logcat is

```
Unable to create JSON directory.
```

After that, I tried to check my application using Android Device. Everything is working fine, I am able to create, store and encrypt the JSON Store using FIPS, in logcat it is showing `FIPSEnabled = true`.

But the problem is, when previously I have created a JSON Store, I was able to see the JSON store using DDMS view, but now I am not able to check the file. Now I want to see where the JSON Store file is available and if it is truly encrypted using FIPS. What is the way to do that?

Comment: What version of Android are you using in the emulator and in the device?

Comment: I am using Android 4.4

Comment: As cnandreu pointed out below, JSONStore support for Android 4.4 is currently being implemented.

Comment: Ok now i am trying to run the same app in Android 4.2.2. Will that support JSON Store

Comment: Yes, Android <4.4 should work as expected; if it does not, let us know.

Comment: Also, you should make sure that JSONStore without FIPS works for you first before making the changes to make it FIPS compliant.

Comment: Sure, i will check the same and update soon

Answer (score 1):

The database file that JSONStore uses will be here:

```
/data/data/com.[app-name]/databases/wljsonstore
```

Replace `[app-name]` with the name of your Worklight Hybrid Android application.

The source of that information is [IBM InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_support.html).

You will need read permission on the device to access that file, for Android usually means you need to have [root access](http://www.androidcentral.com/root).

As of time of writing, if you're using JSONStore on Android v4.4 you may run into issues, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20235695/186909). The IBM Worklight development team is currently working on supporting JSONStore on Android v4.4.