# IBM Worklight 6.1 JsonStore issue on Android 4.4

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have upgraded to Worklight 6.1 & I was with expectation that the issue I mentioned here [IBM Worklight Android 4.4 issue, JSON Store stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20235502/2520370) would be resolved and my app should work fine now. But still facing the JSONStore initialization issue in Android 4.4. Please check below log.

```
12-10 14:58:30.630: D/dalvikvm(14826): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.Test-2/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x41e371b0, skipping init
12-10 14:58:30.630: D/dalvikvm(14826): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Test-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x41e371b0
12-10 14:58:30.630: W/linker(14826): libdatabase_sqlcipher.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
12-10 14:58:30.630: E/dalvikvm(14826): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.Test-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj" referenced by "libdatabase_sqlcipher.so"...
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826): Error during provision
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj" referenced by "libdatabase_sqlcipher.so"...
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:144)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:137)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.openDatabaseIfNecessary(DatabaseManager.java:173)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.checkDatabaseAgainstSchema(DatabaseManager.java:87)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.isSchemaMismatched(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:155)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.ProvisionActionDispatcher.dispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:293)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:87)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:113)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.storage.DispatchingPlugin$SerialExecutor$1.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:147)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 14:58:30.640: E/jsonstore-core(14826):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826): init notification error:----->{
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "src": "initCollection",
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "err": -1,
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "msg": "PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE",
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "col": "Notification",
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "usr": "TestUser",
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "doc": {},
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826):  "res": {}
12-10 14:58:30.650: E/Test(14826): }
12-10 14:58:30.660: E/Test(14826): [wl.jsonstore] {"src":"initCollection","err":-1,"msg":"PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE","col":"Notification","usr":"TestUser","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try the following:**

- Uninstall the application (just to make sure nothing is being cached)
- Go to the application-descriptor.xml
- Remove the JSONStore optional feature
- Build
- Make sure `armeabi/libdatabase_sqlite.so`, `x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so` and `sqlcipher.jar` are removed from the `native` folder under your Android environment. See the picture below under **Files you care about**.
- Go to application-descriptor.xml
- Enable the JSONStore optional feature
- Build
- Make sure `armeabi/libdatabase_sqlite.so`, `x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so` and `sqlcipher.jar` are back. Look at the **FYI** section for more details.
- Refresh the native Android project on Eclipse.
- Run on an emulator or device.

**FYI**

The size and MD5 hashes on my machine (Mac OSX 10.9) for the working libraries. Size was determined with `ls -al` and the MD5 hash was generated with `md5 [file]`.

**sqlcipher.jar**

```
Size: 103300 
MD5 Hash: 8d7f4d682994158096763c24e3d79fb2
```

**armeabi/libdatabase_sqlite.so**

```
Size: 365644
MD5 Hash: 07c4cf69d038c3fdcc7dd0490841ea3d
```

**x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so**

```
Size: 367020
MD5 Hash: 38756d70d256f8e5982ed9789705457f
```

**The files you care about:**

[image: Files]

**Still not working?**

- Create a new Worklight Project with v6.1 (won't work with other versions).
- Create a new Hybrid Application.
- Create an Android environments.
- Go to the application-descriptor.xml
- Enable JSONStore.
- Build.
- Confirm JSONStore works there.

Here's a quick example:

```
var collections = {
    customers : {
      searchFields : {
        'CUSTOMERCODE' : 'string'
      }
    }
  };

  WL.JSONStore.init(collections)

  .then(function () {
    return WL.JSONStore.get('customers').add({'CUSTOMERCODE' : '456'});
  })

  .then(function () {
    return WL.JSONStore.get('customers').findAll();
  })

  .then(function (res) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
  })

  .fail(function (err) {
    alert(err.toString());
  });
});
```

- Copy `armeabi/libdatabase_sqlite.so`, `x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so` and `sqlcipher.jar` from that newly created project that works in Android v4.4 to your existing project. Make sure you build, uninstall a previous version of the app and refresh the native project before you send it to the device or emulator.

Comment: I have just tried this approach, but no success. Same exception is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm was running an out-dated version of the lib. Using 2.2.2 works on 4.4 for me.
Download from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipher+for+Android+v2.2.2.zip)