# Issue with JSON Store for KitKat:Worklight 6.0, Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

it have been issue in running JSON STORE for KitKat in IBM WORKLIGHT v 6.0 i know there is some work around on worklight 6.1 for json store, unless i am trying if there is any patches for older worklight v previous then 6.1 like 6.0 and before.please guide me on process.

Comment: Use the latest version of v6.0, follow the steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20493818/186909) if you run into issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONStore fixes for Android 4.4 "KitKat" are available in the latest fixpack releases:

- [Download 5.0.6.2 Developer Edition](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip)
- [Download 6.0.0.2 Developer Edition](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip)

If you are a customer or business partner and require the Consumer/Enterprise edition, visit [IBM Fix Central](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/&ei=6q1sU8bPLoiU0AWmkIHwDA&usg=AFQjCNHR13_hAa4cTTCt5mxnDy7p8c0HeQ&sig2=__4r1tNzo5IF9PYbhKXFRA&bvm=bv.66330100,d.d2k).

Comment: Hello Idan , i have downloaded 6.0.0.2 developer edition on my system , its upgrade my worklight v from 6.0 to 6.1

Comment: Uh? Well, take a fresh copy of Eclipse, a new workspace and install 6.0.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar for helping us and its working fine but now there is one issue where my code stuck. The issue is now "When we get any new update from server then after downloading Updates my application relaunch then on very first time of launch the application there is same JSON Store issue occuring but when i close the app and relaunch then its working fine." can you pls help me on this why is it generating?

Comment: I don't understand. Please open a new question and explain in detail.